Incorrect redirect to /login causing issues
I keep running into an error on my first React-Spring Boot project that I just cannot work out.
I have an Auth Controller that sets a user session on successful login - which it does. I am getting the correct logs to say that the User session has been set for "User".
I have protected routes that only allow access once logged in. These are working also. I have one endpoint /api/quiz/random that keeps trying to redirect me to /login when it should not. Or at least not where I can see.
The only error message i get is: GET http://localhost:8080/login 404 (Not Found) Quizpage.js:48
Line 48 is the get request to /api/quiz/random. See below.
const fetchQuizItem = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/quiz/random', {
                withCredentials: true,  // Ensures cookies are sent with the request
            });
            console.log('Quiz Item:', response.data);
            setQuizItem(response.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Failed to load quiz item', err);
            setError('Failed to load quiz item');
        }
    };

My QuizController:
package quiz.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import quiz.Entity.QuizItem;
import quiz.Entity.User;
import quiz.Entity.UserQuizAttempt;
import quiz.Service.QuizItemService;
import quiz.Service.UserQuizAttemptService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping("/api/quiz")
public class QuizController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuizController.class);

    @Autowired
    private QuizItemService quizService;

    @Autowired
    private UserQuizAttemptService userQuizAttemptService;

    @PostMapping("/submit")
    public boolean submitQuiz(@RequestParam int guessedYear, @RequestParam Long quizItemId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        logger.info("User object: {}", user);

        if (user == null) {
            logger.error("User not logged in");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User not logged in");
        }

        QuizItem quizItem = quizService.getQuizItemById(quizItemId);
        UserQuizAttempt attempt = userQuizAttemptService.saveUserQuizAttempt(user, quizItem, guessedYear);
        return attempt.getPoints() > 0;
    }

    @GetMapping("/random")
    public QuizItem getRandomQuizItem(HttpServletRequest request) {
        User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        logger.info("User object: {}", user);

        if (user == null) {
            logger.error("User not logged in");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User not logged in");
        }

        return quizService.getDailyQuizItem();
    }
}


I do not see where or why its redirecting me to /login when I have successfully logged in.
2024-07-18 21:08:11.908  INFO 17636 --- [0.0-8080-exec-6] quiz.Service.UserService                 : Authenticating user: willow
2024-07-18 21:08:11.973  INFO 17636 --- [0.0-8080-exec-6] quiz.Service.UserService                 : Authentication successful for user: willow
2024-07-18 21:08:11.974  INFO 17636 --- [0.0-8080-exec-6] quiz.Controller.AuthController           : User session set for: willow
I have tried looking in all of my js pages for anything that could potentially redirect me and its absolutely driving me insane.
My application.properties are as below:

server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=8080

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz_info
spring.datasource.username= 
spring.datasource.password= 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# JPA properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# email properties
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=email@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.same-site=none

logging.level.root=INFO
logging.file.name=myapp.log

My Security Config also:
package quiz.Security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("password"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "PUT"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/api/auth/**").permitAll() // Allow access to login and authentication endpoints
                .antMatchers("/api/quiz/**").authenticated() // Require authentication for quiz endpoints
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll().and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
    }
}



404 means not found. It is the simplest error to deal with, literally means you got your URL wrong. Please provide complete Controller code for the class where getRandomQuizItem so I can check that you don't have any part of the path defined on class level. Also please provide your application.properties (or .yml) so I can check that you didn't define any context path. If you have Spring Security Configuration - please provide that too

I have added what you requested. I have spent all day trying to work out this redirect. Any help is greatly appreciated.
